# Butterfly identification: Dorset England, July.

Tags: species-identification

Can you please identify this butterfly. It was seen in Dorset England 9th July. I think it is a female Silver Studded Blue.[image: Unknown Butterfly]

Comment: see similar species at the bottom of this page - http://butterfly-conservation.org/50-781/silver-studded-blue.html

Comment: see this site too http://www.natureofdorset.co.uk/species/common-blue

Comment: by the way its a lovely image

Comment: Thank you for the response rg255. After continually looking at images on the sites you advised, I finally concluded that it is a Silver-Studded Blue. The spots have worn a little and should be a dominant black like wise the band of orange spots should be more dominant.

Answer (score 3):

The silver-studded blue is frequently found feeding on this plant, cross-leaved heath. There are good numbers of this species to be found on the heaths of Dorset in July and I would suggest that this is certainly silver-studded blue.

Comment: Peter, it would be great if you can add some references.